# Write timestamp on embed message discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm developing a bot and I want to a message to say "Account created today" or something like that (as it does when using timestamp property on embeds) instead of "Account created on 2020-09-02 12:22:47.893000"
The code I have now is this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member)
embed = discord.Embed(
    description=f":inbox_tray: <@{member.id}> joined.",
    colour=discord.colour.Color.dark_green(),

    timestamp=datetime.now()
)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
embed.add_field(name='Account created:', value=member.created_at)

embed.set_footer(
    text=f'User Id: {member.id}')
await client.get_channel(logchannel).send(embed=embed)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```py
        embed = discord.Embed.from_dict({
            "timestamp": str(datetime.utcnow()),
        })
```

Discord will automatically format the text in the post. For instance, for the same day, you will see `Today at h:m PM` at the end of the embed.
I hope this is the answer you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the date when the member joined (*<datetime object>.date()*) to see if it's todays date, if so then put in `Today at h:m PM`, but if not today then you can check if the date is from yesterday by getting todays date (*datetime.datetime.today().date()*) then using the 'timedelta' to take away 1 which basically means it takes away a day from today leaving us with yesterdays date, and then you can check if the member-join date is equal to the date we got (yesterdays date), if so then `Yesteday at h:m PM` as done below. If something else rather than today and yesterday then leave it as `dd/mm/yyyy` as discord does (atleast if I remember correctly)

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
embed.add_field(name='Account created:', value=member.created_at.strftime(
    'Today at %-I:%M %p' if member.created_at.date() == datetime.today().date()
    else 'Yesterday at %-I:%M %p' if member.created_at.date() == (datetime.today() - timedelta(1)).date()
    else '%d/%m/%Y')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use timestamps.

```
import datetime

em = discord.Embed()

em.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

[image: DEMO]